# How do I solve the BSOD that appears during my Windows install?

Tags: windows-7, installation, bsod

In my Core i5 desktop machine I tried to install windows 7 32 bit Ultimate. I received blue screen of death while installing OS. Earlier I had was 64 bit Windows vista which was working fine but now i cant install any of OS.

When I try to re-install OS again same error screen pops up? how can I fix this ? I have 4GB of RAM installed does it have problems with 32 bit OS.

When I install second OS I didn't reformat the entire hard disk.

Comment: WHat's the error code on the BSOD ?

Comment: Reduce the Ram to 2gb, see if installs, if it does, add the ram back after installation is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing OS with external DVD drive I could install the Windwos 7 Ultimate 64 bit edition and it seems to work fine upto now. Some sort of fault in my DVD drive or the DVD drive doesn't recognize by windows OS setup is suspected.

Answer (score 3):

32 bit Windows operating systems will only recognize the first 3gb of ram but having more won't hurt it.

Between 64 and 32 bit installs did you reformat and repartition the drive you're using for the install?

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've had BSoD errors during a Windows install was when there were third-party SCSI/RAID drivers that needed loading.  I would not expect this for a Windows 7 install on a system that previously ran Vista, but it may be something to look up.

Other than that, the only things I've known likely to cause BSoDs since XP, which would also apply during the install process, are faulty hardware components.  CPU, RAM, and Motherboard are the big three "usual suspects" in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your BIOS and see if there is anything about "SATA Operation" or "SATA Mode."  Change it to "ATA mode," if it is currently on "RAID" or "IRRT" mode.  Once it's installed, try switching it back.